# Passing Json images in the View Pager

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to pass the Json data in the view pager, its not showing any errors. But it is also not displaying the images in the view pager, am not able to understand my error

**JSON:http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/banners.php**

Banner.java

```
public class Banner extends Fragment {
    ViewPager bannerpager;
    ArrayList<Data> bannerdta = new ArrayList<Data>();
    BannerAdapter bannerAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View bannerp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner, container, false);
        bannerpager = (ViewPager) bannerp.findViewById(R.id.bannerpager);
        bannerpager.setAdapter(bannerAdapter);
        bannerAdapter = new BannerAdapter(bannerdta, getActivity());
        loadbanner();
        return bannerp;
    }

    private void loadbanner() {
        String bannerurl = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/banners.php";
        JsonObjectRequest bannerreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, bannerurl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray banners = response.getJSONArray("banners");
                    for (int i = 0; i < banners.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject banner1 = banners.getJSONObject(i);
                        Data banndata = new Data();
                        banndata.setBannerimages(banner1.getString("image"));
                        bannerdta.add(banndata);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bannerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(bannerreq);
    }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class BannerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context cntx;
    private ArrayList<Data> blist;
    private LayoutInflater binflater;

    public BannerAdapter(ArrayList<Data> blist, Context cntx) {
        this.blist = blist;
        this.cntx = cntx;
        binflater= (LayoutInflater) cntx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return blist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return object==view;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view=binflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_layout,container,false);
        NetworkImageView bannerimage= (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bannerimage);
        Data bannerdata=blist.get(position);
        ImageLoader imageLoader=AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        bannerimage.setImageUrl(bannerdata.getBannerimages(),imageLoader);
        view.setTag(bannerdata);
        container.addView(view);
        Log.i("Banner", "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]" + " childCount:" + container.getChildCount());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        Log.i("Banner", "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]" + " childCount:" + container.getChildCount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Data data= (Data) ((View) object).getTag();
        int position=blist.indexOf(data);
        if(position>=0){
            return position;
        }else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
}
```

i am including the viewpager from another class to the home page
Home.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/hmebar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            >
            <include layout="@layout/banner"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/hover"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

banner.xml(i had wrote viewpager xml here and included in the Home layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/bannerpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

banner_layout.xml(Single viewpager is the image)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bannerimage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which Imageloader library are you using ?

Comment: i am using volley library

Comment: Can you post the code of NetworkImageView here .

Comment: public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

Comment: This is your NetworkImageView ?? I think this is something else

Comment: it is the image loader i am calling in network images and volley library is having default network image

Answer (score 0):

You not update your `bannerdta` to `bannerAdapter`, so `bannerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will not work.
you can add method `updateData(Data banndata)` in `BannerAdapter.class`
`pubilc void updateData(Data banndata) {
    blist.add(banndata);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}`
and after call network request successfull, use`bannerAdapter.updateData(banndata)`